# changing color and font of specific cells in word table with vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to set up a new table at the end of my document and format it to my specifications. But the backgroundcolor and the textcolor do not seem to work. The Font size also is not exactly what I want, since it applies to the whole table and not only one cell.

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim myRange As Object
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
myRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=myRange, NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=2
With .Tables(.Tables.Count)
    .Cell(1, 1).Select
    With Selection
        .Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
        .Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorWhite
        .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray25
        .Font.Size = 14
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Text = "Hello World"
    End With
End With
```

I want the first row of the table without borders and with font 14, bold, white text on gray background.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the Answer.

The solution is as follows:

```
With .Tables(.Tables.Count)        
    With .Cell(1, 1)
        .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray50
        With .Range
            With .Font 
                .TextColor = wdColorWhite
                .Size = 18
                .Bold = True
            End With
            .Text = "Hello World"
        End With
    End With            
End With
```

I removed the selection of the cell and used it directly. But the real thing was, the use of `.Range` when applying `.Font` and `.Text`