the requested member of the collection does not exist - MS Access DBA
I inherited an MS Access db from someone.  It pulls data from the database and populates a Word template.  I want to improve upon how they were formatting a table.  My goal was to have set widths and alignments for each column.  Below is what I came up with however when I run it I get an error message and "With .Columns(2)" is highlighted.  The error message is: "The requested member of the collection does not exist".  It errors out on Column 2, not Column 1.  I have tried a bunch of different code, using examples I have googled, but have had no success.
Private Sub formatTable()

With m_objWord.Selection
    .SelectCell
    .Font.Bold = True
  
    With .Tables(1)
        .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
        .PreferredWidth = 97
        .Style = "Table Grid"
    End With
    
    With .Columns(1)
         .PreferredWidth = InchesToPoints(2.5)
         .Select
         With Selection.ParagraphFormat
           .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
         End With
    End With
        
    With .Columns(2)
         .PreferredWidth = InchesToPoints(2.25)
         .Select
         With Selection.ParagraphFormat
           .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
         End With
    End With
    
    With .Columns(3)
         .PreferredWidth = InchesToPoints(0.9)
         .Select
         With Selection.ParagraphFormat
           .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
         End With
    End With
         
    With .Columns(4)
         .PreferredWidth = InchesToPoints(1)
         .Select
         With Selection.ParagraphFormat
           .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
         End With
    End With
         
    
End With

End Sub


Word isn't my forte, but I'm guessing it is the .select in the With Columns(1) that is doing it. Your selection only has a single column from that point on.

I confirmed. Remove the Column Select lines and code runs. As with Excel, shouldn't it be possible to manipulate objects without ever using Select?

Is there any merged cell in Word table?

Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010286/changing-color-and-font-of-specific-cells-in-word-table-with-vba


If Selection is inside a Word table, then Selection.Columns(1) represents the column where the insertion point is located. However, Selection.Columns(2) is invalid, resulting in runtime error 5941, as mentioned in the original post.

Sub formatTable()
    Dim oTab As Table
    'Set m_objWord = Word.Application ' for testing
    With m_objWord.Selection
        If .Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            .SelectCell
            .Font.Bold = True
            Set oTab = .Tables(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "Click any cell in table before running the code."
            Exit Sub
            ' you may get the oTab instead of exit sub
            ' Set oTab = m_objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
        End If
    End With
    With oTab
        .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
        .PreferredWidth = 97
        .Style = "Table Grid"
        Dim i As Long, aInch
        aInch = Split("2.5 2.25 0.9 1")
        For i = 1 To 4
            With .Columns(i)
                 .PreferredWidth = InchesToPoints(aInch(i - 1))
                 .Select
                Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = IIf(i < 3, wdAlignParagraphLeft, wdAlignParagraphCenter)
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub

